# Where does ernstnehmen come from?

Tags: etymology

The verb ernstnehmen appears [often in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=ernstnehmen&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50) but nowhere in Duden. Is this regional, or is this verb an example of some other phenomenon of the language?

My question is, if ernstnehmen (or ernst nehmen) is a verb of the German language, why do I not find it in Duden, at all. The closest thing I find is "ernst zu nehmend". So, if it is not in Duden, then where are the users of this verb getting their motivation to use this verb in their writing? I am curious because, I wonder if this is an example of a special phenomenon in the German language, which allows words not recognized as officially German to be commonly used anyway, or what? Because, if it is, then I want to know how to make up these words as well.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear to me. The verb *ernstnehmen* is obvlously composed of *ernst* (serious) and *nehmen* (to take), so the question where it comes from can be answered quite trivially. Or is it about why it is written as one word? That's the question answered by HalvarF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spelling of this verb has changed or has been unified with the [Rechtschreibreform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung_von_1996) (spelling reform) in 1996. That's why you might not find it in newer dictionaries. It was in dictionaries before 1996 though.

My old paper Duden (22th edition from the year 2000) explicitly lists the forms "ernstgenommen" and "ernstzunehmen" as "alte Schreibung" (old spelling). As @DavidVogt commented, the infinitive "ernstnehmen" wasn't listed in Duden even before the reform, so because Duden was the authoritative instance back then, it must have been incorrect, even though it was used.

Before, it was:

> Man muss diese Drohung nicht *ernst nehmen* (*also in use: ernstnehmen*).
> Das ist ein *ernstzunehmendes* Argument.
> Einmal *ernstgenommen*, führt die Theorie zu überraschenden Erkenntnissen.

The new spelling is:

> Man muss diese Drohung nicht *ernst nehmen*.
> Das ist ein *ernst zu nehmendes* Argument.
> Einmal *ernst genommen*, führt die Theorie zu überraschenden Erkenntnissen.

The meaning is *"to take seriously"*.

The spelling "ernstnehmen" was given up quite reluctantly, as you can see in the [Wortverlauf](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=zeitungenxl&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=1&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1946%3A2022&q1=ernst%20nehmen&q2=ernstnehmen). It even seems to be on the rise again in recent years in the newspaper corpus, albeit on a low level.

[image: Wortverlaufskurve ernstnehmen and ernst nehmen]

Changes in "Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung" (separate spelling vs. compound spelling) were among the most controversial of the spelling reform, because in many cases they introduced ambiguities or subtle shifts in meaning.

Some dictionaries seem to view "*ernst nehmen*" as just the verb "*nehmen*" plus an adverb "*ernst*" nowadays, instead of a separate  verb, so they don't even have an entry for it any more.

Comment: I like to add that this happens very often with adverb prefixes. The adverb variant and the prefix variant coexist.

Comment: My pre-reform dictionary has *ernst nehmen* but *ernstgenommen*.

Comment: @DavidVogt thanks for pointing that out. I read my Duden again, and it actually also only explicitly talks about the forms "ernstzunehmen" and "ernstgenommen". I edited.

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that in German it is possible to create new compound words on the spot whch cannot be found in a dictionary. But this is not the case with *ernstnehmen*.

Answer (score 1):

Compare *wahr nehmen*. That is, *ernst nehmen* must have had the same meaning, still pragmatically deduced from the negation, *jmd. hat etwas nicht ernst genommen* - somebody has missed the chance to do something.

It behaves like English "realize" in that respect, which tends to be ambiguous over perception, understanding and action, in a quite behaviorist view.

The lexical connotation of "ernst" more over confers a sense of gravitas.

PS: The difference between *Wahrnehmung wahrnehmen* or *eine Gelegenheit wahrnehmen* is approximately the same as *ernstnehmen* or *ernst nehmen*, *etwas zu Ernst nehmen* (heute müsste man wohl *zum Ernst* sagen, weil das Konzept nunmehr rein plakativ als Unikum gilt, der Ernst des Seins, nicht dein Ernst)